# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'instant' of undefined, ngx-translate angular typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, translation, angular-i18n

Today i'm trying to implement translate service in a ts file like everywhere in my app, first of all have this class :

```js
export class GaugeChartAdapter<T = any> extends ChartAdapter<T> {

  constructor(protected translate: TranslateService) {
    super(translate);
  }

  public process() {
  ...
   options.series = options.series.map(elem => {
      if (lang === 'fr') {
        switch (elem.name) {
          case 'Institution':
            elem.name = this.translate.instant('COMPANY');
    ...

  }
}
```

I have  to implement also in the class ChartAdapter otherwise I got this error :

```js
    Type 'typeof GaugeChartAdapter' is not assignable to type 'new () => ChartAdapter<any>'
```

so I did this :

```js
export abstract class ChartAdapter<T> {
  constructor(protected translate: TranslateService) {
  }

  abstract process(...): any;
}
```

My problem is  that in the navigator I have :

```js
core.js:4098 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'instant' of undefined
```

Thanks for help.

**EDIT**

There is the creation of my Chart factory:

```js
export const graphsOptions: { [name: string]: any } = {
  'gauge': GAUGE_OPTIONS,//comming from a class
  //others graph..
};

export const graphsAdapters: { [name: string]: new () => ChartAdapter<any> } = {
  'gauge': GaugeChartAdapter,
  //others graph..
};

export class ChartCreator {
  public static createChart(key: string, element: HTMLElement, chartParams, callback?: any) {
    graphsOptions[key]['lang'] = chartParams.lang;
    graphsOptions[key]['title'] = chartParams.title;

    if (chartParams.colors && key === 'pie') {
      graphsOptions[key]['plotOptions']['pie']['colors'] = chartParams.colors;
    }
    const adapter = new graphsAdapters[key];
    return chart(element, adapter.process(graphsOptions[key], chartParams.data), callback);
  }

  public static createGauge(key: string, element: HTMLElement, data: any, total: number, lang: string, callback?: any) {
    const adapter = new graphsAdapters[key];
    return chart(element, adapter.process(graphsOptions[key], data, total, lang), callback);
  }

  public static createMap(key: string, data: any) {
    data[0][0] = data[0][0].toLowerCase();
    const adapter = new graphsAdapters[key];
    return new MapChart(adapter.process(graphsOptions[key], data));
  }
};
```

Comment: Hello,

Can you show us how do you instantiate ChartAdapter ? 

it seems that you have forgotten to pass the TranslateService during its instantiation thus resulting in the translate property being undefined (console.log(this.translate))

Comment: I edited my question @MaieonBrix, can you told me if it is what you was waiting for?

Comment: Can you show me RiskChartAdapter ? by your code, a chartAdapter needs to be given a translateService during instantiation.

Comment: For the moment I'm just working with GaugeChartAdapter, i'm not using RiskChartAdapter sorry, but it is the same file  : export class RiskChartAdapter implements ChartAdapter<any> with the contructor that you can see below

Comment: how do you use it ? I want to see the place where you actually write : new GaugeCartAdapter()

Comment: I have a chart factory, I edited my post @MaieonBrix

Comment: Hello  @MaieonBrix I find the solution thanks to you comments and posted the solution. thanks

Comment: Glad you did :) gg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO I found the answer, thanks to @MaieonBrix,

My ts file was not actually a angular So I pass a parameter through the instantiation in my component:

```js
//TS COMPONENT
  constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {
  }

  private renderGraph(): void {
    this.chart = ChartCreator.createGauge('gauge', this.chartTarget.nativeElement, this.chartData,
      this.total, this.lang, this.showInitValue,  this.translate);
  }
```

```js
//Factory
  public static createGauge(key: string, element: HTMLElement, data: any, total: number, lang: string, callback?: any,  translateService?) {
    const adapter = new graphsAdapters[key];
    return chart(element, adapter.process(graphsOptions[key], data, total, lang, translateService), callback);
  }
```

etc...

So translate was undefined because it wasn't in the angular  scope, but by declaring it in the component who call the factory was the solution.